# Hibernate: Association in parent classes should be repeated for child classes

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I want to know that if there is any relationship present in Parent class and Parent1 class. Then can I use the same relationship from Child class to fetch Child1 class.

```java
Class GenericCalendar {
    @JoinColumn(column = "FK_CUR_GEN_CAL")
    GenericCalendarVersion currentGenericCalendarVersion;
}

Class GenericCalendarVersion {
}

Class ProcessingCalendar extends GenericCalendar {
}

Class ProcessingCalendarVersion extends GenericCalendarVersion {
}
```

so i want to retrieve ProcessingCalendarVersion from ProcessingCalendar. Is it possible to get one?

Comment: Do you have user type for your GenericCalendarVersion.class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code u write will be somewhat be like this that u will do inheritance mapping for theprocessing calendar mapping per subclass and same for processing calendar and u will retrieve the processingCalendar object by casting the object returned from the get method of the hibernate session and u can access the processingCalendarversion  object from the loaded object.